# Sending server-side events to GA4 using API

Tags: postman, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I've been using Google's documentation to attempt to build/test server-side events for GA4 using Postman. I've found the [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events#add_to_cart) to work when using their [event builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/ga4-event-builder/) (I see the event in real-time events), but when I transfer it to Postman, it doesn't work (does not show in real-time events). I keep receiving a `403 Forbidden` message. I'm 100% sure I have it set up correctly, but I'm not sure if there's some sort of setting in Google to allow requests from a server instead of a browser (I'm using an out-of-the-box implementation of a GA4 data stream). I've tried sending a User-Agent from my browser in the header and that doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm sending the following:

**METHOD:**

```
POST
```

**URL:**

```
www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=<<MY ID IS HERE>>&api_secret=<<MY API SECRET HERE>>
```

**BODY (RAW TEXT):**

```
{
  "clientId": "783221853.1614059609",
  "events": [{
    "name": "add_to_cart",
    "params": {
            "items": [{
                "item_id": "Robot Toy",
                "item_name": "12345678"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

**HEADERS:**

```
Content-Type: Text/Plain
Content-Length: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong, or if it is an issue with Google and the fact that GA4 is still buggy? Or maybe it thinks I'm a bot and has blocked the traffic?

Comment: Hey, did you find out how this works? I am also wondering why the payload must contain a "client_id".  I want to use the API for server-side event tracking, and there is no such thing as a unique client in this use-case. It wasn't necessary with Universal Analytics either.

Comment: After going through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag#required_parameters), they seems to only mention of firebase and gtag.js. Were you able to get any breakthrough to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

We had the same 403 error and discovered that https:// was missing in front of the URL and the request was denied because of using http only.

Comment: THANK YOU, been beating my head into a wall trying to figure out why it was throwing a 403

Answer (score 0):

Body is correct. But if you send json body you should have:

```
headers = {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
```